pivot_wider in R, pivot all combinations
I have this  data. Lots of people share the same id, but have different details about themselves recorded (name and month are often different).
data.frame(
  id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
  name = c("jane", "laura", "lauran", "lilly", "james", "jimmy"),
  month = c("april", "april", "may", "june", "june", "june")
)





id
name
month




a
jane
april


a
laura
april


a
lauran
may


a
lilly
june


b
james
june


b
jimmy
june



I want a way of pivoting this wider, so each combination of name for each id appears (note: do not need to use pivot_wider if there is a better way).
This data has 1000s of rows in reality.



id
name_1
name_2
month_1
month_2
notes




a
jane
laura
april
april



a
jane
lauran
april
may



a
jane
lilly
april
june



a
laura
jane
april
april
* see below


a
laura
lauran
april
may



a
laura
lilly
april
june



a
lauran
jane
may
april



a
lauran
laura
may
april



a
lauran
lilly
may
june



a
lilly
jane
june
april



a
lilly
laura
june
april



a
lilly
lauran
june
may



b
james
jimmy
june
june



b
jimmy
james
june
june




*ideally solution would not have this row because this combination of names lauran/jane appears in row 1 already jane/lauran etc etc etc on future rows.
However this solution would be ok, if that is as far as we can get.
Some sort of dplyr answer would be amazing but ok without!

Here you go. Easier to use a many-to-many merge than pivot wider in this case.
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE) |> 
  suppressWarnings()

dat <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b",2)), 
  name = c("jane", "laura", "lauran", "lilly", "james", "jimmy"),
  month = c("april", "april", "may", rep("june",3))
)

dat |> 
  # Created row numbers to allow filtering later. Note use of magritta pipe here.
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = id) %>% 
  left_join(., ., by = "id", relationship = "many-to-many", suffix = c("_1", "_2")) |> 
  filter(row_2 > row_1) |> 
  select(id, starts_with("name"), starts_with("month"))
#>   id name_1 name_2 month_1 month_2
#> 1  a   jane  laura   april   april
#> 2  a   jane lauran   april     may
#> 3  a   jane  lilly   april    june
#> 4  a  laura lauran   april     may
#> 5  a  laura  lilly   april    june
#> 6  a lauran  lilly     may    june
#> 7  b  james  jimmy    june    june

Created on 2024-10-29 with reprex v2.1.1

Replace "group mutate ungroup" with mutate(row = row_number(), .by = "id"), this should improve the efficiency a bit more.

Thanks @zx8754 . Great to learn of this new functionality.

A different approach to @JWilliman's, calculating the pairwise combinations directly.
dat <- data.frame(
  id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
  name = c("jane", "laura", "lauran", "lilly", "james", "jimmy"),
  month = c("april", "april", "may", "june", "june", "june")
)

dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      name_pairs <- t(combn(.x$name, 2))
      colnames(name_pairs) <- paste0("name_", 1:2)
      month_pairs <- t(combn(.x$month, 2))
      colnames(month_pairs) <- paste0("month_", 1:2)
      as_tibble(name_pairs) %>% 
        bind_cols(as_tibble(month_pairs)) %>% 
        add_column(id = .y$id, .before = 1)
    }
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  id    name_1 name_2 month_1 month_2
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  
1 a     jane   laura  april   april  
2 a     jane   lauran april   may    
3 a     jane   lilly  april   june   
4 a     laura  lauran april   may    
5 a     laura  lilly  april   june   
6 a     lauran lilly  may     june   
7 b     james  jimmy  june    june   

It's often useful to compare the performance of two different solutions to the same problem.
Assume functions limey and jwilliman have the obvious definitions.
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(limey, jwilliman)
Unit: nanoseconds
      expr min lq mean median uq  max neval
     limey  11 11 32.9     16 21 1241   100
 jwilliman  11 11 22.9     21 21  611   100

Which is faster depends on whether you want to minimise median or mean execution time.  There is no guarantee that performance scales linearly with dimensionality and 100 evaluations is quite small.
Increasing the number of evaluations almost completely removes the differences.
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(limey, jwilliman, times = 10000)
Unit: nanoseconds
      expr min lq    mean median uq max neval
     limey  10 11 16.5740     21 21 701 10000
 jwilliman  10 11 16.6402     21 21 941 10000


You can use sequence + rep to do the same thing as combn does, e.g.,
f1 <- function(x) {
    L <- length(x)
    idx <- rep(1:(L - 1), times = (L - 1):1)
    x[idx]
}

f2 <- function(x) {
    L <- length(x)
    idx <- sequence((L - 1):1, 2:L)
    x[idx]
}

idx1 <- unlist(by(1:nrow(df), df$id, f1))
idx2 <- unlist(by(1:nrow(df), df$id, f2))
with(
    df,
    data.frame(
        id = id[idx1],
        name_1 = name[idx1],
        name_2 = name[idx2],
        month_1 = month[idx1],
        month_2 = month[idx2]
    )
)

which gives
  id name_1 name_2 month_1 month_2
1  a   jane  laura   april   april
2  a   jane lauran   april     may
3  a   jane  lilly   april    june
4  a  laura lauran   april     may
5  a  laura  lilly   april    june
6  a lauran  lilly     may    june
7  b  james  jimmy    june    june

